# Wildfly CI/CD on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jar, wildfly, war

I am trying to build a pipeline for using Jenkins for CI/CD of a JAVAEE/Wildfly
maven application. So, for that I am using the wildfly-deployer plugin on jenkins, and there is this step where to `Copy wildfly-cli-8.2.1.Final.jar to /WEB-INF/lib.` following this link [here](https://plugins.jenkins.io/wildfly-deployer), can you please help on how to do that please?

I moved the jar file to `/root/.jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib`, not sure if that is the correct directory, anws I am getting this error while building:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  13.620 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-04-26T15:07:16Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
FATAL: Unable to initialize command context.
Build step 'Deploy WAR/EAR to WildFly' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```